# Does Battlefield 3 have bots/skrimish maps?

Tags: battlefield-3

I just loved to play Battlefield 1942 and Battlefield Vietnam with bots offline where I could choose map, positions etc., does Battlefield 3 also support playing maps with bots (not other players)?

Comment: No. It's always human players on multiplayer maps. But you could play co-op missions to play with and against bots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Patrick Bach, Executive Producer of Battlefield 3:

> No. We won't have bot-matches in the same way.

There are no bots in Battlefield 3.

[Source](http://www.pcgames.de/Battlefield-3-PC-221396/News/Battlefield-3-Dice-im-Interview-ueber-Kampagne-Multiplayer-Bots-Server-Probleme-und-Call-of-Duty-814499/4/)