# Is it possible to play multiplayer game modes with bots?

Tags: battlefield-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Battlefield 3 have bots/skrimish maps?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34225/does-battlefield-3-have-bots-skrimish-maps)

I know that there are 3rd party software that allows you to add bots to games such as Counter Strike, but I never found such option for Battlefield 3. Are there any bots for this game? Are they official or 3rd party? Where do I find them? Do I have to be online to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not.

The only way you can play by yourself is to play the single player campaign.

Comment: I can only speak for the XBOX360 platform, but this is not an option. I would assume on the PC someone (unofficially) could develop an add on.

Comment: @DavidGrove DICE is yet to release mod tools (don't know if they ever will) so it'll be a long while before someone releases bots, if they ever do.